# How can we execute sequential browser test ?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

resources : VS 2017, Selenium webdriver 3.8 , Nunit 3.9 , FF 56

With this approach how come we can run multiple browser sequentially ? I know we can go to parallel execution in Nunit but I would like to to do sequential execution. I am stuck conceptually as well as pragmatically here. any comment would be appreciated.

**this a GlobalConfig.xml**  - giving key-value pair here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<Automation>
  <RunSettings>
    <AppURL>https:/abcd.com/Login/Login.aspx</AppURL>
    <BrowserType>Firefox</BrowserType>
    <Username>user123</Username>
    <Password>pass123</Password>
  </RunSettings>
  </Automation>
```

---

**this is setting.cs** - defining properties here

```
  namespace Automation.Config
{
    public class Settings
    {
        public static string AppURL { get; set; }
        public static string Username { get; set; }
        public static string Password { get; set; }
       public static string BrowserType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

---

**this is configReader.cs** - used XPathItem class to present items

```
namespace Automation.Config
{
    public class ConfigReader
    {
        public static void FrameworkConfigSettings()
        {
            XPathItem appUrl;
            XPathItem username;
            XPathItem password; 
            XPathItem browserType;

            string strFilename = TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory.ToString() + "\\Config\\GlobalConfig.xml";
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(strFilename, FileMode.Open);
            XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(stream);
            XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

            //Get XML Details and pass it in XPathItem type variables
            // get node content by using simple xpath expression and C#
            appUrl = navigator.SelectSingleNode("Automation/RunSettings/AppURL");
            username = navigator.SelectSingleNode("Automation/RunSettings/Username");
            password = navigator.SelectSingleNode("Automation/RunSettings/Password");
            browserType = navigator.SelectSingleNode("Automation/RunSettings/BrowserType");


            //Set XML Details in the property to be used accross framework
            Settings.AppURL = appUrl.Value.ToString();
            Settings.Username = username.Value.ToString();
            Settings.Password = password.Value.ToString();
            Settings.BrowserType = browserType.Value.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

---

**driver.cs class** - this is the driver class which is taking string name of browser.

```
 public static void Initialize(string browser)
        {

            if (browser.Equals(Constant.Chrome))
            {                
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                Instance = new ChromeDriver(DrivePath, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));
                Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

            }
            else if(browser.Equals(Constant.Firefox))
            {

                FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(DrivePath);
                service.FirefoxBinaryPath = DrivePath;
                var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
                profile.AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true;
                var options = new FirefoxOptions();
                options.AcceptInsecureCertificates = true;
                options.Profile = profile;
                Instance = new FirefoxDriver(service.FirefoxBinaryPath, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));
                Instance.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);           

            }

        }
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity would this be something that would be resolved by using grid?

Comment: I have to run this automation using VM, where things are already tricky and complex so not thinking for Grid now. thanks for your comment.